# Web Data Extraction and Form filling

Tags: java, javascript, c++, firefox-addon-sdk

I am currently beginning the development of a (UI?) backup from a Webplatform. It is not our platform and I don't have access to the source.

I just have the HTML-rendered view of the Form-Data of the elements I entered.

So the task is to browse to the HTML, store the data (XML/JSON) and then login to the site to fill out the forms again to resubmit the data...

At the moment I'm prototyping with C++ QtWebEngine.

What' the best way to do such a task? What are good frameworks for "browsing" the web and analysing HTML?

Solutions in c++/java/javascript (or a firefox-addon?) are preferred.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

same as DSL language interpreter use "Document Object Model (DOM)"
my advice : C# webform app and webbrowser control:

- webbrowser.navigate([url])
- WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event
- WebBrowser.Document (read document and help about "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument" )
- maybe need inject some java script in

/*
please don't use this info for hack and attack
*/

Comment: thanks for advice, but I'm working under Linux and don't really want to dig into Mono. (I just want to use it for kind of backup/restore which isn't provided by the used platform)

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely do something like this using Firefox's Addon SDK. In particular you should look into the [PageWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker) module that allows you to load and run JS code against web pages without showing the page - everything happens in the background.